# Two forms for one input in one page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am building an e-commerce right now and I have two form in one page for doing an order. They are for Add to Cart and Buy Now button. Then, I want to pass the quantity of product that being ordered. But I cannot pass the quantity since there are two forms. So, how do I pass the quantity from one input if there are two forms? I have tried if there were two input for each forms and it works fine but I want to make it as one input. Right now, it works fine for Add to Cart but it doesn't work for Buy Now.

Here is my code.

```
<input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1" id="qty-input" name="quantity" form="cartForm">

<div class="col">
 <form action="/cart-list/add" method="POST" id="cartForm">
  @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product_tops->id}}">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light border border-dark" style="width:100%; background-color:white;">Add to Cart</button>
 </form>
</div>

<div class="col">
 <form action="/buy-now/add" method="POST" id="cartForm">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product_tops->id}}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="width:100%;">Buy Now</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

**Buy Now Controller**

```
public function buyNowQuantity(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $addresses = Address_Delivery_Users::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        $detailaddresses = null;
        $shipments = Shipment::all();
        $products = Product::where('id', '=', $request->product_id)->first();
        $quantityBuy = $request->input('quantity');

        return view('/transactions/delivery_buy_now', compact('addresses', 'detailaddresses', 'shipments', 'products', 'quantityBuy'));
    }
```

Comment: `id="cartForm"`, `id` attributes _must_ be unique on a page, change one of them. You might want to remove `</a>` from `...Buy Now</a></button>`

Comment: okay.. if i change the id, then how do i pass the quantity for buy now? oh right, thankyou for pointing the `</a>` it was a mistake.

Comment: Well you would have to manipulate `form="cartForm"` on the input field then, to have it dynamically associate that field with whatever form you are currently about to submit.

Comment: can you give me an example how to manipulate it? i still don't get it..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this case with adding attribute `formaction` inside `<button>` element.
It will be like this:

```
<form action="/cart-list/add" method="POST">
  @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product_tops->id}}">
   <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1" id="qty-input" name="quantity">

   <div class="col">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light border border-dark" style="width:100%; background-color:white;">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>

   <div class="col">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product_tops->id}}">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="width:100%;" formaction="/buy-now/add">Buy Now</button>
   </div>
</form>
```